# Azure Data Factory Pipeline deployment with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I've create an ADFV2 pipeline that use a variable in it's process. Now I want to export this pipeline to a JSON file in order to use it for a futur deployment.

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to deploy the pipeline in another environment with the powershell command "Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline", it's not working.

The powershell command run normally, but when I'm going to the ADF Interface and select my pipeline, there is an error and the generated JSON does not contains my variable declaration... So the pipeline cannot run...

Do you have any idea why this problem appears?

**Here is the JSON content for my testing pipeline (this pipeline do nothing, it's just for the example):**

```
{
"name": "01_test",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Web1",
            "type": "WebActivity",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "url": {
                    "value": "@variables('test')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "method": "GET"
            }
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "test": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "10"
        }
    }
}
```

}

**And there, the JSON generated on my new environment after the deployment with the powershell command :**

```
{
"name": "01_test",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Web1",
            "type": "WebActivity",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "url": {
                    "value": "@variables('test')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "method": "GET"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
```

}

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem today.

It was a my version of the AzureRM.DataFactoryV2 module.

After I've updated the module, everything works.